# passing a parameter to the link_to method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, parameters, link-to

How do you pass a parameter through the MVC using the link_to method?

view:

```
<%= link_to "Remove Tag", remove_tag_issue_path(issue)%>
```

How do I use the link_to method, to utilize the remove_tag action?

```
issues_controller.rb

  def remove_tag(parameter)
     @issue.remove_it(parameter)
  end
```

issue.rb

```
  def remove_it(parameter)
      self.users.delete(User.find(parameter))
   end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In controller

```
def remove_tag
  @issue.remove_it(params[:my_param])
end
```

And in view

```
<%= link_to "Remove Tag", remove_tag_issue_path(issue, :my_param => "Hello world")%>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the view use the following

```
<%= link_to 'Remove Tag', remove_tag_issue_path(:issue => @issue)%>
```

and in controller

```
def remove_tag
  @issue.remove_it(:issue => params[:issue])
end
```