# How to pass parameters to a controller path after link_to or redirect_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Would like to pass some parameters to the _path for link_to or redirect_to. For example, link_to 'show', customers_show_path(params[:id]) will show the customer with id=params[:id].

What do I do if I want to pass another parameter such as session[:user_id] into the show? Does link_to 'show', customers_show_path(params[:id], :user_id => session[:user_id]) work (retrieve session[:user_id] with params[:user_id] in show)?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

> 'customers', :action => "show", :id =>  1,
>   :user_id =>  2%>

Didn't check, but should work :D

Following are the similar questions:

[pass parameter by link_to ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898737/pass-parameter-by-link-to-ruby-on-rails)

[rails - Pass id parameter on a link_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268254/rails-pass-id-parameter-on-a-link-to)

[passing a parameter to the link_to method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444651/passing-a-parameter-to-the-link-to-method)

http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/57a63381c8bdc6a5?pli=1